# Emacs does not contain package "package"

Tags: package, osx, c, install

I want to add C auto-completion at least so that I can use Emacs on a regular basis as my C editor. I am new to Emacs, and I had already it installed in my system, because it came with the OS (I think). It's version is  22.1.1.

I'm trying to follow the following tutorial:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTUE03LnaXA

To add auto-completion to Emacs, and we started by adding the following code to the `~/.emacs` file:

```
; start package.el with emacs
(require 'package)
; add MELPA to repository list
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
; initialize package.el
(package-initialize)
```

But when I save the file `~/.emacs` and start Emacs again, I get the following message:

> An error has occurred while loading `/Users/cell/.emacs':
>
> File error: Cannot open load file, package
>
> To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
>   cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with the
>   `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
>
> Loading find-func...done find-library-name: Can't find library package

I don't know anything about Lisp, but from my understanding the problem is that the package called `'package` does not exist. Indeed if I try to search it with

```
M-x find-library
```

and then I type `package`, it tells me:

> Can't find library package

According to this answer:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105967/emacs-marmalade-cannot-open-load-file-package

It might be that my Emacs does not have `package`. How can I solve this, and mostly, how can I add auto-completion to C programs?

*Note: I would prefer to stick with this version of Emacs terminal since it came with the OS, apparently. I've also installed another Emacs using a `.dmg` file, but I would like to work on the terminal also (or mostly).*

Comment: If you are on OSX I don't think Emacs would have come preinstalled (though I could be wrong). I also don't know if your issue is caused by having an older version - but your version is quite old. I know you don't want to update, but I think you will run into more issues than this if you do not.

Comment: @elethan OS X includes GNU Emacs 22, the last version released under GPL 2.

Comment: @lunaryorn thanks for the info! I was assuming that since it doesn't come pre-packaged with most Linux distributions that it wouldn't come packaged with OS X.

Answer (score 8):

OS-X comes with emacs 22, which is several years out of date. One easy way to get a current emacs is by downloading from http://emacsformacosx.com/. This will give you package.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the one I installed (apart from the one I had already). The problem is that I would like to run Emacs also from the terminal, and the command `emacs` is by default connected to the Emacs which comes with the OS...I know I can add the new installed Emacs to the path, but is there a way to make this new one the default one?

Comment: Adding the new emacs to the path should do the trick, just put it at the front. I've got this in my .bash_profile: `export PATH=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS:$PATH`

Comment: Yes, it did the trick, thanks! And to start it without the windowing system, I also add the following alias: `alias="emacs -nw"`, if someone is interested.

Comment: I have a question: does the dmg-installed Emacs also refers to the `~/.emacs` before initialising or does it refer to its own initial-options launching file?

Comment: The same ~/.emacs